# Finding the Galois Correspondence of polynomial $t^4-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

For the polynomial $t^4-2$ in $\Bbb Q[t]$, the splitting field is given by $\Bbb Q(\alpha, i)$ where $\alpha$ is $2^{1/4}$.

I figured out that the Galois group of this polynomial is the dihedral group $D_4$, whose order is $8$.

And also I found that there are $10$ subgroups of $D_4$, which means that there are $10$ intermediate fields between $\Bbb Q(\alpha, i)$ and $\Bbb Q$ (including themselves).

But, I keep failing to find what those intermediate fields actually are. I found $\Bbb Q$,  $\Bbb Q(\alpha, i)$,  $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ ,$\Bbb Q(\alpha i)$,  $\Bbb Q(\alpha^2)$,  $\Bbb Q(\alpha^2i)$, $\dots$, but need $4$ more. Could anyone show me what the remaining fields are?

Comment: I can see one obvious one you are missing: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Have you used the fact that the degree of any intermediate extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the index in $D_{4}$ of the subgroup it corresponds with? Note that $D_{4}$ has five subgroups of order $2$, and $3$ subgroups of order $4$, so there should be $5$ intermediate fields with degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $3$ quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Try to learn how to properly write mathematics in this site: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Let $H$ be a subgroup of the Galois group. Let $x$ be an element of the splitting field. Then $y=\sum_{h\in H}h(x)$ will be an element of the fixed field of $H$ (proof left to the reader). If you make a poor choice of $x$, you will get a useless element $y$; then try again, with a different $x$. Eventually, you will get an element $y$ (or maybe you'll need two elements) which generate the fixed field of $H$ (Galois theory will tell you the degree of the fixed field, so you'll know when you have generators), so you will have found one more intermediate field. Keep going.